# Bash: replacement of string with quotes (bad substitution error)

Tags: string, bash, replace

I am trying to modify lines of a file through a bash script (version 3.2) and have tried many options, but they all give a 'bad substitution error'.

For example, I extract the line from $filename (previously defined variable)

```
line=$(sed -n 24p $filename)

echo ${$line/coordinateIndex="0"/coordinateIndex="124"}
```

I am trying to replace the coordinateIndex to some other numbers. Those numbers are between "" in the file and I need to keep that format.

Any help appreciated; thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ${$line/coordinateIndex="0"/coordinateIndex="124"}
```

should not have the $ inside:

```
echo ${line/coordinateIndex="0"/coordinateIndex="124"}
```

You may also need to quote it properly to properly match the double-quotes.

```
echo ${line/coordinateIndex=\"0\"/coordinateIndex="124"}
```

And it's also better to enclose your argument around double-quotes to prevent word splitting with values of IFS and unexpected pathname expansion:

```
echo "${line/coordinateIndex=\"0\"/coordinateIndex="124"}"
```

See more detail about usage of [Parameter Expansion in the Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: Your last suggestion works perfectly! Thank you also for the link to the manual.

Comment: Can I follow up with another question? How can I modify that command for the case where I do not know the length of the old value of coordinate index (could be 10s, 100s, 1000s, etc)? I tried echo "${line/coordinateIndex=\"*\"/coordinateIndex="124"}" but it clearly doesn't work.